# React native app crashed when release mode - build success , but can't open

Tags: react-native, release

my react native app crashed in release mode. debug apk works for me. but the release mode crashed. release mode also BUILD SUCCESSFUL. but when it opened app crashed.

I can't find what the issue was.

i run `adb logcat *:E.` also

then [image]

[image]

i cant find what's error showing in adb logcat *:E.

how to slove this issue. help

Comment: Hi, do you have another keystore for release? Have you updated the signingConfigs for release? In the buildTypes the release must be like this                                  `release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release 
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.debug // use this for appcenter
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }`